# Getting Facebook shares for URL without query parameters using FB graph

Tags: facebook

Looking for a way to get the total number of shares or likes for a page, excluding it's query parameters.

If the URL is:

```
http://example.com/book?id=123
```

I would like to know the total number of times the

```
http://example.com/book
```

has been shared.

Using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://example.com/book?id=123
```

works, but only for that title, which is not what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: Different query string parameters make a _different_ URL, and different URLs are different Open Graph objects to Facebook. If you wanted to count the shares and likes for different URLs as one, then you would’ve had to specify a common `og:url` for all of them to begin with (but then they all would use the same OG meta data when shared, too.) If you don’t want that, then you can only request the numbers for each URL individually, and add them up on your end.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @CBroe. I had made the change to the og:url already, but wanted to know if it was a way to aggregate all the previous shares.